# Why is it returning -1 when when I search for 1 with binarySearch method in Collections class in java

Tags: java, collections

See this code:

```
package learningjava;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Java{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List obj = new ArrayList();
        obj.add(2);
        obj.add(4);
        obj.add(6);
        obj.add(1);

        int bs = Collections.binarySearch(obj,6);
        System.out.println(bs);
    
    }
}
```

Here I am using binarySearch method in Collections class. I am using it to find the position of 6 in this list. Here it is returning 2 which is correct.

But if I try to find the postion of 1 in this list it is returning -1.

```
 package LearningJava;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Java{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List obj = new ArrayList();
        obj.add(2);
        obj.add(4);
        obj.add(6);
        obj.add(1);

        int bs = Collections.binarySearch(obj,1);
        System.out.println(bs);
    
    }
}
```

The output is -1.

Why is it returning -1 instead of 3. The problem is only with 1.
If I try to find the position of  other numbers, it is working correctly.

Comment: The duplink is for the method in `Arrays`, but the root cause is the same.   The [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) only works on sorted arrays / collections.

Answer (score 1):

As per binarySearch method , input List **must be sorted according to natural order** otherwise result will be undefined which is happening in your case.

**Refer:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)

```
Adding Collections.sort(obj) before below line will give the desired output.

int bs = Collections.binarySearch(obj,1);
```

**Updated code:**

```
 List obj = new ArrayList();
            obj.add(2);
            obj.add(4);
            obj.add(6);
            obj.add(1);
//Input list must be sorted as below
            **Collections.sort(obj);**

            int bs = Collections.binarySearch(obj,1);
            System.out.println(bs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method) prior to making this call.

Javadocs are a wonderful thing

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)